# comtypes.gen attributes are different from self download and conda pre-installation

Tags: anaconda, python-3.7, comtypes

I have created my own Anaconda environment. I needed to use the 'comtypes' package to connect to the software ETABS, so I first downloaded it with the conda installation command and then I tried the next command line:

`helper = comtypes.client.CreateObject('ETABSv17.Helper')`

But, I received the next error:

`AttributeError: module 'comtypes.gen.ETABSv17' has no attribute 'cHelper'`

However, I realized that if a try the same command line with the base environment coming with Anaconda, that includes a pre-installed 'comtypes' package, there is no problem. In fact, if I check comtypes.gen.ETABSv17 with my customized environment and with the one from Conda, there is a huge difference between available attributes, even when they have the same version number: comtypes 1.1.7.

How can I get the exactly same 'comtypes' package that comes with Anaconda in order to have all the associated attributes working?  Maybe, could there be some package dependence that I am missing?

Pd: I am using Windows10 and I have tried it in Pycharm and Spyder with Python 3.7

Thank you all !

Comment: Can you share the command(s) you used to create the environment? What else does the environment contain?

Answer (score 0):

I  had this issue and i was using python 32 bit version. So uninstalled and installed a 64 bit version and now its working fine. May be this helps